# Send requests to a server one at a time with RxJS

Tags: asynchronous, rxjs

I have an array of payloads I want perform a couple async actions on each and then send to a server. I'm trying to do it like this:

```
Rx.Observable.from(payloads)
    .flatMap(item => ... do something A something async, return modified payload)
    .flatMap(item => ... do something B)
    .flatMap(item => ... post to server)
    .subscribe();
```

This works....

But it seems to do A for each payload all at once, then B for each payload all at once, then post each payload all at once.

With lists of potentially thousands of payloads. Is there any way to go through the payloads one at a time, one step at a time?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/rxjs/8247/common-recipes/28035/sending-multiple-sequential-http-requests#t=201703030657084292099

Answer (score 2):

If they need to be done a->b->c for each payload:

```
Rx.Observable.from(payloads)
  .concatMap(payload => doA())
  .concatMap(resA => doB())
  .concatMap(resB => doC())
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

concatMap will wait until the previous emission completes before starting the next. This will limit your concurrency.

Comment: Good one! Shouldn't answer questions while still sleepy